# Firebase: keep listening to ChildEventListener though app exits

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase for creating a small chat application. I want `ChildEventListener` to keep listening to the firebase database location though my app is in background or it is exited. Currently I am registering it and when my app exits or closed using `finish()`, after that none of my methods of ChildEventListener are getting called like `onChildAdded` or `onChildChanged` though I haven't called `removeEventListener`.I want ChildEventListener to be always running in background. Is there anyway of doing that?

Comment: Hello, you found any solutions for this?

Comment: No, but don't call `removeEventListener` and I guess it should work for you!

Comment: Ok. You mean ChildEventListener will always work in background thread even app is kill OR we need to do all this stuff in service?

Comment: I guess it will be killed when we kill app manually or the Android OS kills our app when resources are required, so we need to handle it manually!

Answer (score 10):

Use service to listen your ChildEventListener

```
    public class ChildEventListener extends Service {
        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            //Adding a childevent listener to firebase                
            Firebase myFirebaseRef = new Firebase("FirebaseURL");
            myFirebaseRef.child("FIREBASE_LOCATION").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    //Do something using DataSnapshot say call Notification
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(FirebaseError error) {
                    Log.e("The read failed: ", error.getMessage());
                }
            });

          }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                    Log.e("The read failed: ", firebaseError.getMessage());
                }
            });

            return START_STICKY;
       }

  }
```

register your Service inside Manifest

```
    <service android:name=".ChildEventListener "/>
```

Start your Service and listen for childEvents, where/when to start your service is up to your chat app design

Comment: but when I will start my existing instance of service, then it will register the ChildEventListener again which is causing multiple listeners of ChildEventListener. Is there anyway to check that my ChildEventListener is already listening?

Comment: Use sharedPreferences to check whether your childEvent listener is  active or not.If it is not listening then only add that event listener

Comment: thats what I am saying, how to check that ChildEventListener? is there any listener that will tell me its not listening?

Comment: why are you starting existing instance of Service again..If your service is running above code will listen for childEvent Listener.Using ActivityManger you can check whether your service is running or not otherwise you need start the Service

Comment: and what is the probability that if my service is running the ChildEventListener will also be running?

Comment: what if service is killed if background data off or auto restart mode off and any other reason? during service off period i will miss data

Answer (score 0):

Try firebase cloud messaging with firebase functions.