# sending gcm upstream from iOS app when app is not in foreground + gcm API for uploading APNs certificate

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have two questions about `APNs push notification` using `gcm` library.

1. Does `gcm` or `fcm` have a **public api** for uploading `APNs certificates`? I need to do this automatically instead of manually.
2. It seems that sending **upstream** using `gcm` library in an `iOS app`, only works when app is in foreground. Is it correct? Is there any workaround to send upstream even when app is not open or is in background? I want to send notification **click event** using `gcm` **upstream** to my server and it is highly preferable to do it instantly.

   I am aware that I can save this click event and send it when app become active, but it is possible that user does not open the app for a long time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *1. Does gcm or fcm have a public api for uploading APNs certificates?*

There is currently no public API for uploading APNs Certificates. For FCM (and any new projects), it's only done via the [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/settings/cloudmessaging/). Also, it seems that making use of the APNs Authentication Keys over certificates seem more convenient now ([APNs Overview](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/APNSOverview.html)).

> *2. It seems that sending upstream using gcm library in an iOS app, only works when app is in foreground. Is it correct?*

Yes. There has to be a connection for upstream messaging to work.

> Is there any workaround to send upstream even when app is not open or is in background?

AFAIK, no. As mentioned in the [FCM doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/upstream#send_an_upstream_message_from_an_ios_client_app) (emphasis mine):

> To send messages upstream to the server, an iOS client app composes a message, connects to FCM, and calls [`sendMessage`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasemessaging/interface_f_i_r_messaging.html#a183be72b9c3829975984e491737048e7).
>
> To connect, set the `shouldEstablishDirectChannel` flag to `YES` in the `AppDelegate`. **FCM manages the connection, closing it when your app goes into the background and reopening it whenever the app is foregrounded.**
>
> ...
>
> The FCM client library caches the message on the client app and sends it when the client has an active server connection. On receiving the message, the FCM connection server sends it to the app server.

It mentions that FCM manages the connection, however AFAICT, there is this limitation for iOS devices that limits apps to maintain running services if the app is in background/closed (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41549900/4625829)). And if a connection can't be established, upstream messaging won't work.

As general practice, data passed through FCM should as much as possible *improve the user experience* and that no app critical data is passed.

> *I am aware that I can save this click event and send it when app become active, but it is possible that user does not open the app for a long time.*

It's possible. But it's also highly unlikely for a user to not click on a push notification immediately after it displays. In that scenario, the usual action would be for the user to immediately click on the notification while there is still  an open connection.